# Test component in particular state in with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

One of my React components require to have a certain state value set before rendering a part of the component. I want to be able to set the desired state with the React Testing Library in order to test the component in this particular state.

Simplified version of component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    renderPartOfComponent: false
  };
}

renderPartOfComponent() {
  this.setState({ renderPartOfComponent: true });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.renderPartOfComponent && <div>This is visible when state is true</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Test:

```
test("test component", () => {
  // Pass something to set renderPartOfComponent to true
  const { getByText } = render(<Component />);
  expect(getByText("This is visible when state is true")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: You don't update the state directly by using something from `react-testing-library`, you rather mimic user interactions using `react-testing-library` that will update the state as it is supposed to be updated by your component.
Can you put some more code to show us how `renderPartOfComponent` is updated ?

Comment: I suspected that. I've added a method for it just like it's intended to be used.

Comment: You're testing two things here, state and rendering. You could extract the rendering part to a stateless component that takes the boolean as a property. That way it's super easy to test as you simply pass the state you want to render.

Comment: When do you call the `renderPartOfComponent` function? That is key to understanding your component. For example, if you call that function on click of a button, then your test should click that button.